# authentication with a service account on Colab

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I am using tensorflow on Colab. First I create a new Colab page using my regular gmail account. Then as I understand I need to run tensorflow with a google service account. So I created a credential.json file using the Google Cloud IAM. I stored it in my gmail account google drive. At the beginning of my notebook code, I first mount my gmail google drive and verified that I can find my credential.json. Then I declared an env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to this file.

Here is the situation. If I don't point to this credential.json, I can pass the line

```
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Then it fails on

```
tensorflow_gcs_config.configure_gcs_from_colab_auth()
```

due to the fact that it is looking for the default file adc.json.

If I do set the env variable, then the code fails at

```
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Looks like I have to either create a Colab notebook using the service account, or create a credential file for my gmail account. I could not find instructions for doing either.

Please provide instructions to fix this.

The entire code section is:
ON_CLOUD = True

```
if ON_CLOUD:
  print("Setting up GCS access...")
  import tensorflow_gcs_config
  from google.colab import auth
  # Set credentials for GCS reading/writing from Colab and TPU.
  TPU_TOPOLOGY = "v3-8"
  try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  # TPU zdetection
    TPU_ADDRESS = tpu.get_master()
    print('Running on TPU:', TPU_ADDRESS)
  except ValueError:
    raise BaseException('ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the previous cell in this notebook for instructions!')
  auth.authenticate_user()
  tf.config.experimental_connect_to_host(TPU_ADDRESS)
  tensorflow_gcs_config.configure_gcs_from_colab_auth()
```

scenrio 1: no declaration of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. The errors is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/adc.json' due to the code
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distpackages/tensorflow_gcs_config/**init**.py in configure_gcs_from_colab_auth(device)
130   adc_filename = os.environ.get(
131       "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "/content/adc.json")

scenrio 2: I declare GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. The error is
AuthorizationError: Failed to fetch user credentials
on this line

```
auth.authenticate_user()
```

apparently because I am using my regular gmail account to create this Colab notebook.

Basically, the conflict is

1. don't declare GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, the code expects adc.json which doesn't exist.
2. declare GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, the authenticate_user call fails because GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS uses my service account, not my gmail account.

Comment: You may try this line of code `credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)
` where `key_path` would be the path of of the json file in your google drive

Comment: You can see the entire code section where the errors occur. Where do I add your line of code defining credentials? the 'credential' variable is not used any where in the code.

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are facing while running the code for better resolution of the issue.